# Converting line feature to MBtiles through engine, but line is getting messed up and forming helix

Tags: geojson, mbtiles, smart-data-compression

We have been trying to upload a line feature (Road Network) on Maptiler cloud through Maptiler engine as a MB tile, after uploding the line is getting jagged and misshapen.

I tried using geojson, Shapefile and geopackage as well still the same issue.
[Data in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er5sr.png)

[image: Data after converting it as a MBtile through engine]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

Its a rendering issue, to solve the above problem you need to render your data at the zoom you want to show your data in the Maptiler Engine. 10CPU core system or more would be recommended.